# Fix inconsistency with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association in my model and it experienced an intermittent bug (in production) when it was created. I fixed it, but now I need to repair entries created under this bug.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_protected :userable
end

class UserType1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class UserType2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

So, the problem is that I have some entries on my user table without relation with their polymorphic table.

Record Example (users table):

```
id  userable_id userable_type
999 null        UserType1
```

And UserType1 hasn't any entry related.

So I made a query to detect all entry errors:

```
SELECT users.* from users where COALESCE(userable_id, 0) = 0'
```

But I don't know how to repair it cleanly.

My idea is create a script like this:

```
User.find_by_sql('SELECT users.* from users where COALESCE(userable_id, 0) = 0').each do |user|
  userable = user.userable_type.classify.constantize.new
  userable.user = user
  userable.save
  user.userable = userable
  user.save
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to build and save an userable? methods called on nil problems?

Comment: Suggest a title: "How to write rake task to manipulate database"

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  alias_method :old_userable, :userable

  def userable
    old_userable || Userable.new
  end

end
```